# Concatenation in hive query

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a hive table like

```
col1   col2
1     ["apple", "orange"]
1     ["orange", "banana"]
1     ["mango"]
2     ["apple"]
2     ["apple", "orange"]
```

There data types is

```
col1 int
col2 array<string>
```

I want to query something like :

```
select col1, concat(col2) from table group by col1;
```

Output should be :

```
1    ["apple", "orange", "banana", "mango"]
2    ["apple", "orange"]
```

Is there any function in hive to do this ?

Also I write this data to csv and when I read it as a dataframe I get the col2 dtype as `object`. Is there a way to output it as an `array`.

Answer (score 1):

Try by exploding the **array** then use **`collect_set`** function by grouping by `col1`.

**`Example:`**

**`Input:`**

```
select * from table;
OK
dd.col1 dd.col2
1       ["apple","orange"]
1       ["mango"]
1       ["orange","banana"]
```

---

```
select col1,collect_set(tt1)col2 from (
   select * from table lateral view explode(col2) tt as tt1
)cc 
group by col1;
```

**`Output:`**

```
col1    col2
1       ["apple","orange","mango","banana"]
```

Comment: There are  a lot of rows in the array and exploding is causing an memory issue.